# How to invite a new user to be co-administrator in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, administrator, user-management, azure-subscription

I'm pulling my hair out trying to do what I thought was a simple matter of adding an external co-administrator to my Azure subscription.  Here's what I've done so far:

1. From Azure AD, went through the "Invite External User" workflow to invite the user
2. The invitation email was received and the user clicked "Accept", and went through the sign up process, however, when they sign in they're taken to some "My Applications" site that's blank.  I expected them to be taken to Azure's portal...
3. I tried to add them as a co-administrator by going to my subscription, clicking "Access control (IAM)", and clicking "Add co-administrator", but their user account doesn't show up in the list of users to choose from, and can't be found using the search, what gives??

I've gone back to Azure AD, and tried all sorts of things, I gave them "Global Administrator" rights, had them log in again, but nothing seems to work, no matter what I do they do not appear in the list for adding a co-administrator.

Somebody must have an easy step-by-step guide showing how to do this.  I've read numerous articles, but they all say go to "Access Control IAM", click "Add Co-Administrator" and select the user, and don't provide any help for when the user I want to select isn't in the list.  This is beyond frustrating...

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, yes this is a straight forward process to the add the guest users to Azure IAM roles, just wanted to check guest user (invited) are you able to see in the Azure AD Directory (users list) as guest user, if yes you should be able to assign Azure roles to the guest account, same steps have been shared over here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-external-users
If the issue still persists, please contact support.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Givary, but I've assigned the "Owner" role to user in question, but when they login to https://portal.azure.com/, they don't see any directories or subscriptions and just get a "Welcome to Azure!" page with "Start with an Azure free trial" links, how do I get them to have access to my subscription?